# Reading multiple lines text file as one element

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, text-files

My goal is to do some text mining in spark. I am using SPark 2.1. Therefor I need to read text files and save them as elements of an RDD/DataFrame. My Issue is that in spark each line is interpreted as one element, but I want each text file getting one element of the RDD. The code I have written yet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
spark = SparkSession\
       .builder\
       .getOrCreate()

for i in range(510):
if i < 9:
    b = "00" + str(i+1) + ".txt"
elif i < 99: 
    b = "0" + str(i+1) + ".txt"
else:
    b = str(i+1)+".txt"  
if i == 0:
    a = spark.read.text("hdfs:///user/vkocamer/bbc/business/"+b )
    c = a
else:
    d = c
    a = spark.read.text("hdfs:///user/vkocamer/bbc/business/"+b )
    c = a.union(d)
```

I have done that already before with python and pandas and it worked:

```
input = []
for i in range(510):
  if i < 9:
     b = "00" + str(i+1) + ".txt"
  elif i < 99: 
     b = "0" + str(i+1) + ".txt"
  else:
    b = str(i+1)+".txt"  
  a =open("C:\\Users\\VKocamer\\Desktop\\bbc\\business\\"+b).read().rstrip("\n")
  input.append(a)
```

I guess that I need something like

> rstrip("\n")

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sc.wholeTextFile("hdfs:///user/vkocamer/bbc/business/*.txt")`?

Comment: Actually I found this solution while searching the web but it did not work.... anyway now it is working, obviously I have done something wrong...thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can read your entire file with:

```
val fileInput = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to file")
```

as `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]` which will include file path and the entire content of your file. Then you can access content requesting second element of your RDD